# Exclude Column From Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, min

I have a table, Supplies, that lists the prices for items from different suppliers:

```
| ID | Item | Price | Supplier |
```

*ID* is the primary key (just an auto-generated integer).
*Item* is the name of the product. *Price* is the price of the product. *Supplier* is a foreign key (integer).

I want to list the cheapest price and supplier for each item.

I'm relatively new to databases and so far I've got this:

```
SELECT Name, MIN(Price), Supplier FROM Supplies GROUP BY Name
```

This of course gives me the error that

> *Supplier* is not in an aggregate function or group by clause.

I have done some Google searching and read quite a few articles and answers on the subject but they all seem to be for much more complicated situations than mine and confuse me (as said, I don't have much experience with databases and SQL) or they just talk about the error and not how to get around it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: If two or more prices are the same, do you want any tie-breaker logic?

Comment: Using HSQLDB. 

If two or more prices are the same I would prefer it if it displayed both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your RDBMS, you may be able to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a ranking to each record and pick the one's that rank first.  This is faster than using additional joins or correlated sub-queries, but isn't, for example, supported in MySQL at present.

```
WITH
    sorted_supplies AS
(

    SELECT
        supplies.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY price)   AS price_ordinal
    FROM
        supplies

)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sorted_supplies
WHERE
    price_ordinal = 1
;
```

Without the support for `ROW_NUMBER()` then you're pretty much steered down the road of additional aggregations and joins...

```
SELECT
    supplies.*
FROM
    supplies
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        name,
        MIN(price)   AS min_price
    FROM
        supplies
    GROUP BY
        name
)
    AS min_prices
        ON  min_prices.name      = supplies.name
        AND min_prices.min_price = supplies.price
```

Do note that this query will return all suppliers with the same price if they're all tied for the lowest price.

The first query can be Forced to do that by using `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Second method works as desired. Thank you very much, and for the quick response too.

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you can use the ANSI standard window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, min(price) over (partition by item) as minprice
      from supplies
     ) s
where price = minprice;
```

Comment: @MatBailie . . . It would make more sense that the goal is to get the smallest price per item, not per supplier.

Answer (score 1):

You could rank the results, later selecting the lowest/highest ranking item (based on sort order). Assuming You're using SQL Server 2008 or higher:

```
SELECT
    Item, Price, Supplier
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Price ASC) PriceRank
        , Item
        , Price
        , Supplier
    FROM
        Supplies
    ) supplies_ranked
WHERE
    PriceRank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the issue is this - what if you have more than one supplier that offers the gear for the exact same (lowest) price?  What Supplier should be returned in the result set then?

The way to accomplish what you're after would be to get the min price, then outer join back to the same table on product = product and price = price and such.  Understand though, that if you have the scenario above, you will return two rows - one with each supplier that offers that minimum price.

3 or 4 new answers have popped up here since I started composing this, so I'm willing to guess the actual code already exists.  I'll leave this text here as is as the "plain English" explanation as to why the query can't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `partition by` (some sql-ish environment like Access) then you can also do this:

```
select s.name, s.supplier, s.price from
(select name, min(price) as min_price from supplies group by name) mp
join supplies s on mp.name=s.name and mp.min_price = s.price
```

This is not nearly as efficient as the `partition by` because it has a sub-query for lowest price for each name.  Note that it will return multiple suppliers in the event of a tie; you may or may not want that.